# What is the order that iOS remove the app(in background) in memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I wonder that..

What is the order that iOS remove the app(in background) in memory?

Memory usage size DESC? enter background order?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.


Comment: Unless he's talking about what delegate method he should implement to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `applicationWillTerminate:`?

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

See the events your app should respond to in [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate)